# Does kanade Lucas Image alignment have any relation to tracking?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, tracking, opticalflow

I am confused with Image alignment and tracking because they are dealt together in many lectures. Does kanade Lucas Image alignment have any relation to tracking? If yes how is image alignment used in tracking?

Comment: tracking is (or can be) related to finding the same object's/pixel's positions in multiple images, same holds for image alignment. It's a bit like asking whether the job as a postman is related to the job of a chimney sweeper, because both have to walk from house to house to do their job.

Answer (score 3):

Lucas-Kanade (aka Kanade-Lucas-Tomasi, aka KLT) is an algorithm for finding point correspondences between two images. The resulting correspondences, in turn, can be used for many different vision tasks, such as image alignment, tracking, or 3D reconstruction.